# Inconsistent time performance for numpy `std`

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have some Python code which involves taking the standard deviation across axes of a `numpy` array. Typically my array has dimensions of approximately `[100,500,2]`. I am finding that in my code, if I try and take the standard deviation across the `0`th axis, the code performs very slowly. i.e. if I do something like:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------

t1 = time.time()

# Perform standard deviation using numpy function
std_out = np.std(my_array, axis=0, ddof=1)

t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)

# --------------------------------------------------------------
```

I get an output of around `0.0034` to `0.0058` seconds. However, if I run each of the `2`nd axes seperately like so:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------

t1 = time.time()

# Initialize empty array
std_out2 = np.zeros(my_array.shape[-2:])

# Perform standard deviation using numpy function on each of the last axis seperately
std_out2[...,0] = np.std(my_array[...,0], axis=0, ddof=1)
std_out2[...,1] = np.std(my_array[...,1], axis=0, ddof=1)

t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)

# --------------------------------------------------------------
```

I get an output of around `0.00076` seconds. I have checked and `std_out` and `std_out2` are equal and have the same datatype (`np.float64`). I cannot understand why this would be.

What is even weirder is, when I tried to generate a small working example so that I could ask this question on stack overflow, the two above approaches performed the same in terms of time. In other words, I only observe this time difference when this code is embedded in the rest of my code. This happens even if I run each of the above approaches directly one after another, using exactly the code given above.

I cannot work out why this is happening and I don't know where to start in terms of reducing this poor time performance. Has anyone any idea why this might be happening? Could it be caused by some form of memory issue?

Comment: Be advised that `time.time()` is not meant to measure performance. You should use the module `timeit` or the `%timeit` magic in ipython.

Comment: Ah okay thank you - I wasn't aware of this before!